# PyInstaller ModuleNotFoundError for 'docx' Despite Using --hidden-import

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, docx

**I want to be able to run my Python script on Windows simply by double-clicking on an executable file, without needing to install Python or other libraries first.**

I'm trying to create a standalone executable from a Python script using PyInstaller. My script uses the `docx` and `pandas` libraries, among others. However, when I run the executable generated by PyInstaller, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for the 'docx' module.

I used the following PyInstaller command to generate the executable, including the `--hidden-import` option for the `docx` module:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed "C:/Users/nicol/Downloads/numero.py" --hidden-import docx
```

Despite this, I still receive an error when running the executable. Additionally, there are several warnings about missing libraries in the build log, which I'm not sure are relevant to the issue.

```
Traceback/Error Message:
When executing the .exe file, the following error appears:
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "numero.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'

Warnings from PyInstaller:

I also received several warnings during the build process:

```
Warnings written to C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpacblyi50\build\numero\warn-numero.txt
```

```
129561 WARNING: Hidden import "pysqlite2" not found! ...
```

##### Script Overview:

Here is an overview of my script's code:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import re
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QPushButton
import difflib

def get_file_path(caption, file_type):
    file_dialog = QFileDialog()
    file_path, _ = file_dialog.getOpenFileName(caption=caption, filter=file_type)
    return file_path

def load_excel_data(excel_path):
    try:
        return pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name='Feuil1', header=0, names=['n°', 'nom de la pièce jointe', 'classeur', 'conclusion', 'Col5', 'Col6'])
    except Exception as e:
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Erreur de chargement", f"Erreur lors du chargement du fichier Excel: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

def update_word_document(word_path, df):
    updates = []  # Liste pour stocker les informations de mise à jour
    try:
        doc = Document(word_path)
        for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
            match = re.search(r'pièce n° \d+', paragraph.text)
            if match:
                update_paragraph(paragraph, match, df, updates)
        return doc, updates
    except Exception as e:
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Erreur de traitement", f"Erreur lors de la mise à jour du document Word: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

def update_paragraph(paragraph, match, df, updates):
    old_piece_number = match.group()
    piece_info = paragraph.text.replace(old_piece_number, '').strip().strip('-').strip()
    new_piece_number = find_matching_piece_number(piece_info, df)
    if new_piece_number:
        new_text = paragraph.text.replace(old_piece_number, f"pièce n° {new_piece_number}")
        updates.append(f"Mise à jour: '{paragraph.text}' à '{new_text}'")
        paragraph.text = new_text


def find_matching_piece_number(piece_info, df):
    # Assurez-vous que piece_info est une chaîne
    piece_info = str(piece_info).lower()

    # Créer une liste de noms de pièces jointes en tant que chaînes
    piece_names = df['nom de la pièce jointe'].apply(lambda x: str(x).lower())

    # Chercher la meilleure correspondance possible
    best_match = difflib.get_close_matches(piece_info, piece_names, n=1, cutoff=0.6)
    if best_match:
        matching_row = df[piece_names == best_match[0]]
        if not matching_row.empty:
            return matching_row.iloc[0]['n°']
    return None

def display_updates(updates):
    dialog = QDialog()
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Mises à jour effectuées")
    dialog.setModal(True)  # Rendre le dialogue modal
    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    text_edit = QTextEdit()
    text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
    text_edit.setText("\n".join(updates))
    layout.addWidget(text_edit)

    close_button = QPushButton("Fermer")
    close_button.clicked.connect(dialog.close)
    layout.addWidget(close_button)

    dialog.setLayout(layout)
    dialog.exec_()  # Exécuter en tant que dialogue modal
    QApplication.instance().quit()  # Fermer l'application une fois le dialogue fermé

def main():
    excel_path = get_file_path("Sélectionnez le fichier Excel", "Excel Files (*.xlsx)")
    word_path = get_file_path("Sélectionnez le fichier Word", "Word Files (*.docx)")
    df = load_excel_data(excel_path)
    doc, updates = update_word_document(word_path, df)
    save_path = get_file_path("Sélectionnez l'emplacement de sauvegarde", "Word Files (*.docx)")
    doc.save(save_path)
    
    # Afficher les mises à jour dans une boîte de dialogue
    if updates:
        display_updates(updates)
    else:
        QMessageBox.information(None, "Aucune mise à jour", "Aucune modification n'a été apportée au document.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)  # S'assurer que l'application se termine avec la dernière fenêtre
    main()
```